# Long Table with Long Caption

Tags: captions, longtable

I have a long table with many rows and columns over many pages. Due to my longness of caption, I cannot see the overall table content properly. When I try my code with a shorter caption, table seems fine. Is there a way to overcome? Any help is appreciated. I am also open to alternative, simple long table templates.

```
\begin{longtable}
{|l|l|l|l|c|l|l|l|c|c|c|} 
\hline
\textbf{n} &\textbf{$M$} &\textbf{$A_s$} &\textbf{$A_d$} &\textbf{Space} &\textbf{$D_m$} &\textbf{$D_s$} &\textbf{$D_d$} &\textbf{Delay} &\textbf{Space x Delay} &\textbf{Algorithm} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{11}{c}%
{\textit{ Continued from previous page} } \\
\hline
\textbf{n} &\textbf{$M$} &\textbf{$A_s$} &\textbf{$A_d$} &\textbf{Space} &\textbf{$D_m$} &\textbf{$D_s$} &\textbf{$D_d$} &\textbf{Delay} &\textbf{Space x Delay} &\textbf{Algorithm} \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{11}{c}{\tablename\ \thetable \text{: }{Polynomial Multiplication Delay Optimization Result \protect(No Padding, $M=A_s=A_d$, $D_m=D_s=D_d$)}} \\
\endfoot
\hline
\caption{Polynomial Multiplication Delay Optimization Result (No Padding, $M=A_s=A_d$, $D_m=D_s=D_d$)}
\endlastfoot
\label{Table:Polynomial Multiplication-1}
1&1&0&0&1&1&0&0&1&1&Initial Condition\\
2&4&0&1&5&1&2&0&3&15&SB\\
\end{longtable}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: `\caption` would not have that effect but you used a `\multicolumn{11}{c}` which like all `c` columns forces the text on one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I would rather use `xltabular` package instead of `longtable`. It prescribe table width (for example to be equal to `\textwidth`)
- For both caption I would use `\caption` command (see MWE below)
- It is quite unusual to insert caption at bottom of table, this require some trick for make space for intermediate captions and more important, at use of the `xltabular` package, complicate caption numbering.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell, xltabular}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\listoftables

\section{Long table}
\lipsum[1-3]
\begingroup
    \small
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \addtocounter{table}{1}
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|r|l|l|l|c|l|l|l|c|c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}
    \hline
\thead{n} & \thead{$M$}     & \thead{$A_s$} & \thead{$A_d$}
          & \thead{Space}   & \thead{$D_m$} & \thead{$D_s$}
          & \thead{$D_d$}   & \thead{Delay} & \thead{Space x\\ Delay}
          & \thead{Algorithm}   \\
    \hline
\endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{11}{c}%
    {\textit{ Continued from previous page} } \\
    \hline
\thead{n} & \thead{$M$}     & \thead{$A_s$} & \thead{$A_d$}
          & \thead{Space}   & \thead{$D_m$} & \thead{$D_s$}
          & \thead{$D_d$}   & \thead{Delay} & \thead{Space x\\ Delay}
          & \thead{Algorithm}   \\
    \hline
\endhead
    \hline
    \multicolumn{11}{c}{}\\[-3ex]
\caption[]{Polynomial Multiplication Delay Optimization Result (No Padding, $M=A_s=A_d$, $D_m=D_s=D_d$)}
    \smallskip
    \addtocounter{table}{-1}
\endfoot
    \hline
    \multicolumn{11}{c}{}\\[-3ex]
\caption[Polynomial Multiplication Delay Optimization Result]
        {Polynomial Multiplication Delay Optimization Result (No Padding, $M=A_s=A_d$, $D_m=D_s=D_d$)}
    \endlastfoot
\label{Table:Polynomial Multiplication-1}
%
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1  & Initial Condition\\
2 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 3 & 15 & SB\\
3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1  & Initial Condition\\
4 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 3 & 15 & SB\\
5 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1  & Initial Condition\\
6 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 3 & 15 & SB\\
7 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1  & Initial Condition\\
8 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 3 & 15 & SB\\
9 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1  & Initial Condition\\
10 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 3 & 15 & SB\\
11 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1  & Initial Condition\\
12 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 3 & 15 & SB\\
\end{xltabular}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

**Addendum (Off-topic):**

I would design your table on more usual and "professional" way:

- captions on the top of table
- notes for continuation of table at table bottoms
- for numbers use `siunitx` package
- removed vertical lines

For table I should use `tabularray` table with its library `siunitx` (it load `siunitx` package). It require just one compilation for final form of table.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{geometry}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
  \ExplSyntaxOn
\NewChildSelector{eachtwo}
  {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn {2}{2}{\l_tblr_childs_total_tl}
      { \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tblr_childs_clist {##1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\listoftables

\section{Long table}
\lipsum[1-3]
    %\small
    \SetTblrStyle{contfoot-text}{font=\small\itshape, gray3}
    \SetTblrStyle{caption-text}{font=\small}
    \SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{font=\small\bfseries}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Polynomial Multiplication Delay Optimization Result (No Padding,\\ $M=A_s=A_d$, $D_m=D_s=D_d$)},
  entry = {Polynomial Multiplication Delay Optimization Result},
  label = {tab:tblr}
                ]{rowhead = 1,
                 colsep=5pt,
                 colspec={@{} Q[c, si={table-format=2.0}] 
                          *{8}{c}
                          X[c, si={table-format=2.0}]  
                          X[2,j]
                          @{} },
                 hline{1,Z} = 1pt, hline{2}=0.6pt,
                 row{1} = {mode=math},
                 row{2-Y} = {rowsep=-0.5pt},
                 row{eachtwo} = {abovesep=1ex},
                 } 
% column headers  
n   & M     & A_s   & A_d 
    & \SetCell[c=1]{mode=text} Space   
    & D_m   & D_s   & D_d 
    & \SetCell[c=1]{mode=text} Delay   
    & \SetCell[c=1]{m,mode=text} {{{Space x Delay}}} 
    & \SetCell[c=1]{c,mode=text} Algorithm \\
% table body
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1  & Initial Condition\\
2 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 3 & 15 & SB\\
3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1  & Initial Condition\\
4 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 3 & 15 & SB\\
5 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1  & Initial Condition\\
6 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 3 & 15 & SB\\
7 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1  & Initial Condition\\
8 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 3 & 15 & SB\\
9 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1  & Initial Condition\\
10& 4 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 3 & 15 & SB\\
11& 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1  & Initial Condition\\
12& 4 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 3 & 15 & SB\\
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your solution , and precious suggestion. I am going to reconsider changing my table structure accordingly, and generate it in a more professional manner.